# Grabbed object not being dropped by raycast when colliding with object on same layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have objects that can be grabbed and carried by the first-person player. The raycast checks only on one layer that all objects that can be picked up are on.

If the objects bumps into an object NOT on the same layer, the held object is dropped, since the ray is no longer hitting the grabbed object. This is the expected behavior.

However, if the grabbed object bumps into an object on the same layer, the object is NOT dropped. I believe this is because the ray continues to register that an object on the layer is still selected.

How can I set it up so the raycast knows it has switched objects, and to drop the current object?

Any help is much appreciated!

Here's an example of what's going on:

https://reddit.com/link/cgfyg0/video/5zk5ylbh0wb31/player

Here's the code that controls the player's raycast to check if object can be grabbed:

```
public class PlayerPickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Public variables
    public float rayLength;
    public bool objectSelected;

    // Private variables
    Camera camera;
    RaycastHit hit;
    GameObject hitObject;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Set layerMask as layer 10
        int layerMask = 1 << 10;

        // Create ray and check for object hit
        if( Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection( Vector3.forward ), out hit, rayLength, layerMask ) )
        {   
            // Set objectSelected to true
            objectSelected = true;

            // Set hit object as hitObject
            hitObject = hit.collider.gameObject;

            // Set hitObject's selectedByPlayer var to true
            hitObject.GetComponent<AnimalGrab>().selectedByPlayer = true;

            // Draw debug line
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.blue);
        }
        // Object no longer being selected
        else if( objectSelected )
        {
            // Set objectSelected to false
            objectSelected = false;

            // Set hitObject's selectedByPlayer var to false
            hitObject.GetComponent<AnimalGrab>().selectedByPlayer = false;
        } 
        // Ray has not hit anything
        else {
            // Sit hit object as empty
            hitObject = null;

            // Draw debug line
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * rayLength, Color.yellow);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code that controls the object being grabbed:

```
public class ObjectGrab : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Public variables
    public bool beingHeld;
    public bool selectedByPlayer;
    public GameObject selfObject;
    public GameObject tempParentObject;
    public GameObject playerObject;

    // Private variables
    float throwForce;
    float lookSpeed;
    float targetDistance;
    Vector3 selfPosition;
    Rigidbody rb;
    float selfDistance;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Assign rigidbody component
        rb = selfObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Set beingHeld as false
        beingHeld = false;

        // Set initial throwForce
        throwForce = 1000f;

        // Set initial lookSpeed
        lookSpeed = 10f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Calculate distance from parent object
        selfDistance = Vector3.Distance( selfObject.transform.position, tempParentObject.transform.position );

        // If being held
        if( beingHeld == true )
        {
        // Set velocity to 0
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

        // Set as child of GrabPoint
        selfObject.transform.SetParent(tempParentObject.transform);

            // ROTATION

            //Distance between target and the actual rotating object
            Vector3 targetDistance = playerObject.transform.position - transform.position;  

            // Calculate the Quaternion for the rotation
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Slerp( transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation( targetDistance ), lookSpeed * Time.deltaTime );

            //Apply the rotation 
            transform.rotation = rot; 

            // put 0 on the axis you do not want for the rotation object to rotate
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3( 0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0 ); 

            // THROWING

            // If right click pressed
            if( Input.GetMouseButtonDown( 1 ) )
            {
                // Add force to self
                rb.AddForce( tempParentObject.transform.forward * throwForce );

                // Set beingHeld as false
            beingHeld = false;
            }
        }
        // If not being held
        else
        {
            selfPosition = selfObject.transform.position;
            selfObject.transform.SetParent( null );
            rb.useGravity = true;
            selfObject.transform.position = selfPosition;
        }

        // If not being selected by player
        if( selectedByPlayer == false )
        {
            // Set beingHeld as false
            beingHeld = false;
        }
    }

    // Mouse Down
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if( selectedByPlayer == true )
        {
            // Set beingHeld as true
        beingHeld = true;

            // Disable gravity
        selfObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;

            // Enable collision detection
        selfObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().detectCollisions = true;
        }
    }

    // Mouse Up
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        // Set beingHeld as false
        beingHeld = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html)? I think that might be the issue. Your current object is triggering the hit so the object behind it doesn't register.

Answer (score 1):

In the first if of the update function:

```
if( Physics.Raycast[...])
```

you can do another check to test whether the hit object has changed like this:

```
if(hit.collider.gameObject != hitObject)
{
    // The object changed
}
```

Then handle the object change there.